# How to commit/rollback all sessions that were generated from a SQLAlchemy engine when the session variable is no longer available?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to have SQLAlchemy issue a commit or rollback for all sessions that were generated from an engine or connection?

I created a session from within a function, but forgot to commit within the function. Now all my tables that were being operated on within that function are locked and I'll have to contact a DBA, as I no longer have a reference to the `session` variable upon which to commit or rollback.

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(con_str)

def foo(session):
    conn = session.connection()
    conn.execute(some_table.update().value(...)
    # Forgot to commit here

def main():
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()
    foo()
```

Of course now my table is locked and I can't do anything.

Comment: Just restart the process?

Comment: @univerio does sqlalchemy issue a rollback if you restart during a transaction?

Comment: If you have a transaction started, and disconnect from the server, the transaction will be discarded. No `ROLLBACK` command will be explicitly issued, but the effects will be the same.